# The Threejs model sets the position to (0, 0, 0), but the scene display is not (0, 0, 0)

Tags: three.js, model, position, gltf

I encountered problems with the model setting position when I developed with Threejs today

This is my loader Gltf Model code  (typescript)

```
const loadGltf = (url: string, name: string) => {
    loader.load(url, (gltf) => {

        const object = gltf.scene.children[0]
        object.name = name
        object.position.set(0, 0, 0)

        if (scene) {
            scene.add(object)
            scene.add(new THREE.BoxHelper(object, new THREE.Color(0xffff00)))
        }

    })
}
```

but..the scene show like this

[The position of sphereMesh is (0, 0, 0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DquzI.png)

I checked the document for a long time, but there is no relevant description.
How can I solve this problem?
If you understand, can you tell me? This can do me a great favor!!

Comment: Note that there may be many objects nested under the scene, with different positions. You'll need to use `scene.traverse((object) => { ... })` to modify all of them. You might find it easier to recenter the object in Blender and re-export, so you don't have to do this at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I think the gltf model you're loading has its origin set as away from the object itself. If this is a model you've created, try opening it in Blender or a similar program and make sure its origin point is located on the model itself.

When you call yourObject.position.set() in threejs it will be relative to the origin point of the 3D shape, rather than the physical object that you see visually.

Comment: How can the size of the model be measured?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I tried adding a THREE.AxesHelper to the model, and found that obejct is not at the coordinates (0, 0, 0) of gltf.scene. Can I copy the model separately and put it in my scene?